# Article about a future in which Virgin monopolised most big companies

Tags: story-identification

I came across this article written as (I think) a winning entry for a contest. As far as I remember, the contest was about how Orwell got the surveillance facts wrong as a prediction for the year 1984. The contest was basically for a story about the year 2048 or 2084 (as far as I remember).

As far as the particulars of that entry are concerned, it started off speaking about how companies like Microsoft (this was before the Apple boom) were now called Virginsoft, and how Virgin had basically monopolized most of the big companies.

It then went on to mention that surveillance was a reality, but a knock on your door was more likely to be a pizza delivery guy seeing that you're hungry rather than some sort of secret police.

Any help regarding the source of this story, and the story itself will be deeply appreciated. I'm sorry that I'm unable to give more facts regarding this. I read it a very long time ago.